# Why would an UPSERT to QuoteLineItem fire validation rule configured for Opp Products?

Tags: apex, workflow, validation

I am upserting a group of items into QuoteLineItem, but for some reason, an Opportunity Product Validation Rule is failing (Opp not Quote).

The custom field being validated exists in both objects (QLI and OP), but I'm confused as why the validation would be triggered at all as it for a different object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Quote was sync'd then any change to the QLI would cause a corresponding change to the OLI (Opportuntiy Product).

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense as the quote may very well have been synced.  That being said, it still should have passed the validation as the required information existed. Back to the drawing board...